# ELementTree first child function is missing

Tags: python, xml, parsing

I am writing a parser in python to parse an xml file. For that I need to get tag name but when I am doing so, along with tag name I am getting namespace also. Alongwith this, I need to get the first child at many positions which I am unable to find any attribute in this package (Elementtree). I searched a lot but could not find out as how to get only tag name without namespace value and first child also. The trialinput.xml file is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<nf:rpc-reply xmlns:nf="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:netconf:base:1.0" xmlns="http://www.cisco.com/nxos:1.0:ip">
 <nf:data>
  <show>
   <ip>
    <interface>
     <__XML__BLK_Cmd_ip_show_interface_command_brief>
      <__XML__OPT_Cmd_ip_show_interface_command_operational>
       <__XML__OPT_Cmd_ip_show_interface_command_vrf>
        <__XML__OPT_Cmd_ip_show_interface_command___readonly__>
         <__readonly__>
    <TABLE_intf>

        <ROW_intf>
                <vrf-name-out>default</vrf-name-out>
                <intf-name>Vlan10</intf-name>
                <prefix>9.1.1.1</prefix>
                <ip-disabled>FALSE</ip-disabled>
                <iod>104</iod>
                <proto-state>TRUE</proto-state>
                <link-state>TRUE</link-state>
                <admin-state>TRUE</admin-state>
               </ROW_intf>
        <ROW_intf>
                <vrf-name-out>default</vrf-name-out>
                <intf-name>Vlan23</intf-name>
                <prefix>23.1.1.9</prefix>
                <ip-disabled>FALSE</ip-disabled>
                <iod>103</iod>
                <proto-state>TRUE</proto-state>
                <link-state>TRUE</link-state>
                <admin-state>TRUE</admin-state>
             </ROW_intf>
             <ROW_intf>
                <vrf-name-out>default</vrf-name-out>
                <intf-name>Po1</intf-name>
                <prefix>4.9.1.2</prefix>
                <ip-disabled>FALSE</ip-disabled>
                <iod>111</iod>
                <proto-state>TRUE</proto-state>
                <link-state>TRUE</link-state>
                <admin-state>TRUE</admin-state>
             </ROW_intf>
             <ROW_intf>
                <vrf-name-out>default</vrf-name-out>
                <intf-name>Po2</intf-name>
                <prefix>5.9.1.2</prefix>
                <ip-disabled>FALSE</ip-disabled>
                <iod>112</iod>
                <proto-state>TRUE</proto-state>
                <link-state>TRUE</link-state>
                <admin-state>TRUE</admin-state>
             </ROW_intf>
             <ROW_intf>
                <vrf-name-out>default</vrf-name-out>
                <intf-name>Po3</intf-name>
                <prefix>6.9.1.2</prefix>
                <ip-disabled>FALSE</ip-disabled>
                <iod>113</iod>
                <proto-state>TRUE</proto-state>
                <link-state>TRUE</link-state>
                <admin-state>TRUE</admin-state>
             </ROW_intf>
    </TABLE_intf>
    </__readonly__>
        </__XML__OPT_Cmd_ip_show_interface_command___readonly__>
       </__XML__OPT_Cmd_ip_show_interface_command_vrf>
      </__XML__OPT_Cmd_ip_show_interface_command_operational>
     </__XML__BLK_Cmd_ip_show_interface_command_brief>
    </interface>
   </ip>
  </show>
 </nf:data>
</nf:rpc-reply>
```

The code that I am writing is (in progress of completion, has given just to give a gist of what I am trying to get as an output):

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

print "before skip()"
def skip(root):

    print "rootname.tag in skip == %s" %(root.tag)
        if(root.tag == "readonly"):  // here if I compare with the namespace then returns the value
        print "skip -> if"
        return root
    else:
        print "skip-> else"
        root = root[0]
        print "new root %s" %root
        return skip(root)

xmlDoc = ET.parse("trialinput.xml")  
dict = {}
print "accessing the root"
root = xmlDoc.getroot()

print "rootname == %s" %root.tag
pointerOfReadonly = skip(root)

print "pointerOfReadonly.tag %s" %pointerOfReadonly.tag

print "accessing child of readonly"
tableInitiationPointer = pointerOfReadonly[0]   // Here how to get the first child of readonly tag?


#print "accessing children of table"
#allRows = tableInitiationPointer.childNodes

Print "no of rows in the table = %s" %tableInitiationPointer.len("ROW_intf")// Returning none due to above non ability to find the tag
for row in tableInitiationPointer:
    for subrows in row:
        key = subrows.tag
        value = subrows.value
                dict[key]=value
```

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 1):

To get rid of the namespace on a tag:

```
import re
def GetBareTag(tag): return re.sub(r'{.*?}', '', tag)
```

To find the first child:

```
def GetFirstChild(e): return e[0] if len(e) else None
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are missing is the correct use of namespaces.

Since you have namespaces in your xml file, the nodes will have the namespaces and ET will return the namespace along with the `tag`.

Try something like below to extract the correct nodes:

```
xmlDoc = ET.parse("trialinput.xml")  
dict = {}
print "accessing the root"
root = xmlDoc.getroot()

print "rootname == %s" %root.tag
pointerOfReadonly = root.findall(".//{http://www.cisco.com/nxos:1.0:ip}__readonly__")
print pointerOfReadonly
```

The first 2 nodes, `rpc-reply` and `data`, will contain namespace `"urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:netconf:base:1.0"` and others will contain `"http://www.cisco.com/nxos:1.0:ip"`

For an overview on `xpath` syntax and usage, check the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xpath-support)

Therefore when you search for node `__readonly__` you need to explicitly specify the namespace in the `findall()` method like:

```
pointerOfReadonly = root.findall(".//{http://www.cisco.com/nxos:1.0:ip}__readonly__")
print pointerOfReadonly
```

which prints a list of all the found nodes (in our case only 1):

```
[<Element '{http://www.cisco.com/nxos:1.0:ip}__readonly__' at 0x20b4990>]
```

You need to then follow similar technique with other nodes you want to search. 
For e.g. now if you want to look for node `ROW_intf`, you can do something like:

```
pointerOfRowIntf = root.findall(".//{http://www.cisco.com/nxos:1.0:ip}ROW_intf")
print pointerOfRowIntf
```

which then prints all 5 found nodes:

```
[<Element '{http://www.cisco.com/nxos:1.0:ip}ROW_intf' at 0x20d4990>, <Element '{http://www.cisco.com/nxos:1.0:ip}ROW_intf' at 0x20d4bb0>, <Element '{http://www.cisco.com/nxos:1.0:ip}ROW_intf' at 0x20d4db0>, <Element '{http://www.cisco.com/nxos:1.0:ip}ROW_intf' at 0x20d4f90>, <Element '{http://www.cisco.com/nxos:1.0:ip}ROW_intf' at 0x20dc190>]
```